# Firefox: ogv and webm video format dont fire

Tags: 15.04, firefox, video, websites

I have problem with ogv and webm video format in my firefox - dont work. Do you have any suggestion why ? In chrome all works nice and smoth. On windows all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is because of the lack of H.264 codec support on Firefox.

Try to install the FFmpeg plugin for GStreamer :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```